# Solaris 10 - password expired, enter new password, access denied

Tags: linux, solaris-10

I am new to Solaris OS.
I implementation few security polices on my solaris machine, after few days, it notifies --warning your password has expired, please change it now, Enter new password: (i gave every type of combination here), it says --Access denied--, enter password.
-I tried all of my user-accounts.

I reset all passwords in /etc/password and shadow file (boot from CD and mount disk)
I change values in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, /etc/default login and /etc/defaults/password
2x machines in cluster, both behaving same, services are running on 1x node other is being used for managing this issue.
Please guide.
Thanks.

More:
I even commend (using # sign) /etc/default/login, /etc/default/passwd, /etc/ssh/sshd_config files for almost all entries.
I, tried to reset passwords using /etc/shadow file by removing encrypted entries, it say to enter "new password" afterwards "Access denied"
I am using putty to access machines.
During implementation of polices, i disable following services as well:
Telnet
FTP
finger
sendmail
rlogin

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to all of you, issue has been resolved.
Solution:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcshadow-file/

Value at the 4th " : " of each user was mistakenly change to 91 days, that the reason system was not allowing me to change the password.